# CASE WHEN this value display the value of that column for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am trying to figure out my `CASE` logic. If the value of the `FABRIC RANGE` column equals `_SPECIAL`, then display the value of `Description` column.

So, we currently get the below:

```
PO NUMBER            FABRIC RANGE                   DESCRIPTION
P18030096           Fiesta Indigo            Indigo   
P18030097           _SPECIAL                 Dolly Denim
P18030098           Quantum Nebula           Nebula
P18030098           _SPECIAL                 Dolly Magenta
```

What we want is it to see is to give this result:

```
  PO number            Fabric Range                Description
P18030096           Fiesta Indigo                Indigo   
P18030097           Dolly Denim                  Dolly Denim
P18030098           Quantum Nebula               Nebula
P18030098           Dolly Magenta                Dolly Magenta
```

my code is:

```
SELECT   dbo.PO.PONo AS [PO Number], 
                     dbo.ReceivingDetails.ItemVendorNumber AS [Fabric Range], dbo.ReceivingDetails.Description
```

I know I need to put CASE WHEN, but it might be a good idea :(

Comment: If `PO.PONo` is not a column name in the `ReceivingDetails` table, then we need to see the table definition for the `PO` table (if there is such a table). Otherwise, my answer has assumed this is just a poorly/confusing named column name in the `ReceivingDetails` table. If the table `PO` does exist, then you would need to `JOIN` the `PO` table to `ReceivingDetails`. . . Something like: `INNER JOIN PO p ON rd.ID = p.ID`

Comment: Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Do you need more help with this?

Comment: hi brien! thank you so much! those suggestions really helped me worked on this report.

Answer (score 1):

The column name `ItemVendorNumber` doesn't make sense considering it isn't a number, but I see that is what you are using in your example query. Same goes with `PO.PONo` (unless that is your literal column name `[PO.PONo]`?)

```
SELECT PO.PONo [PO Number]
    ,CASE WHEN rd.[ItemVendorNumber] = '_SPECIAL'
            THEN rd.[DESCRIPTION]
        ELSE rd.[ItemVendorNumber]
        END [FABRIC RANGE]
    ,rd.[Description]
FROM ReceivingDetails rd
```

HERE IS A [[DEMO]](http://rextester.com/GJML21077)

---

Test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE ReceivingDetails ([PO.PONo] VARCHAR(50)
                               , ItemVendorNumber VARCHAR(100)
                               , Description VARCHAR(500))

INSERT INTO ReceivingDetails
VALUES ('P18030096','Fiesta Indigo','Indigo'),  
       ('P18030097','_SPECIAL','Dolly Denim'),
       ('P18030098','Quantum Nebula','Nebula'),
       ('P18030098','_SPECIAL','Dolly Magenta')


--verify
SELECT * FROM ReceivingDetails

--results OP asked for
SELECT [PO.PONo] [PO Number], CASE 
        WHEN rd.[ItemVendorNumber] = '_SPECIAL'
            THEN rd.[DESCRIPTION]
        ELSE rd.[ItemVendorNumber]
        END [FABRIC RANGE], rd.[Description]
FROM ReceivingDetails rd
```

[image]

Comment: such a great help! it also works on my end. :) thanks heaps